# Counting Rows under a Specific Header Row

Tags: sql, oracle, count

I am trying to count the number of rows under specific "header rows" - for example, I have a table that looks like this:

```
Row # | Description      | Repair_Code | Data Type
1     | FRONT LAMP       | (null)      | Header
2     |  left head lamp  | 1235        | Database
3     |  right head lamp | 1236        | Database
4     | ROOF             | (null)      | Header
5     |  headliner       | 1567        | Database
6     | WHEELS           | (null)      | Header
7     |  right wheel     | 1145        | Database
```

Rows 1, 4 and 6 are header rows (categories) and the others are descriptors under each of those categories. The Data Type column denotes if the row is a header or not.

I want to be able to count the number of rows under the header rows to return something that looks like:

```
Header     | Occurrences
FRONT LAMP | 2
ROOF       | 1
WHEELS     | 1
```

Thank you for the help!

Comment: TRY this way SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM tableName where Description=FRONT LAMP

Comment: ... and you'd get exactly **1**, @CODINGDOJO (which is not what the OP wants, I believe).

Answer (score 0):

Data model looks *wrong*. If that's some kind of a hierarchy, table should have yet another column which represents a "parent row#".

The way it is now, it's kind of questionable whether you can - or can not - do what you wanted. The only thing you can rely on is row#, which is sequential in your example. If that's not the case, then you have a problem.

So: if you use a `lead` analytic function for all header rows, then you could do something like this (sample data in rows #1 - 7; query that might help begins at line #8):

```
SQL> with test (rn, description, code) as
  2    (select 1, 'front lamp'     , null from dual union all
  3     select 2, 'left head lamp' , 1235 from dual union all
  4     select 3, 'right head lamp', 1236 from dual union all
  5     select 4, 'roof'           , null from dual union all
  6     select 5, 'headliner'      , 1567 from dual
  7    ),
  8  hdr as
  9    -- header rows
 10    (select rn,
 11       description,
 12       lead(rn) over (order by rn) next_rn
 13     from test
 14     where code is null
 15    )
 16  select h.description,
 17         count(*)
 18  from hdr h join test t on t.rn > h.rn
 19                        and (t.rn < h.next_rn or h.next_rn is null)
 20  group by h.description;

DESCRIPTION       COUNT(*)
--------------- ----------
front lamp               2
roof                     1

SQL>
```

---

If data model was different (note `parent_rn` column), then you wouldn't depend on sequential row# values, but

```
SQL> with test (rn, description, code, parent_rn) as
  2    (select 0, 'items'          , null, null from dual union all
  3     select 1, 'front lamp'     , null, 0    from dual union all
  4     select 2, 'left head lamp' , 1235, 1    from dual union all
  5     select 3, 'right head lamp', 1236, 1    from dual union all
  6     select 4, 'roof'           , null, 0    from dual union all
  7     select 5, 'headliner'      , 1567, 4    from dual
  8    ),
  9  calc as
 10    (select parent_rn,
 11            sum(case when code is null then 0 else 1 end) cnt
 12     from test
 13     connect by prior rn = parent_rn
 14     start with parent_rn is null
 15     group by parent_rn
 16    )
 17  select t.description,
 18         c.cnt
 19  from test t join calc c on c.parent_rn = t.rn
 20  where nvl(c.parent_rn, 0) <> 0;

DESCRIPTION            CNT
--------------- ----------
front lamp               2
roof                     1

SQL>
```

Comment: There was a column that was cut out of the table - the Data Type column might be what you were referring to.

Answer (score 0):

I would approach this using window functions.  Assign a group to each header by doing a cumulative count of the `NULL` values of `repair_code`.  Then aggregate:

```
select max(case when repair_code is null then description end) as description,
       count(repair_code) as cnt
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when repair_code is null then 1 else 0 end) over (order by row#) as grp
      from t
     ) t
group by grp
order by min(row#);
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=e7e03abe9a4eb7de278bc597e6e567f7) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: There is a db<>fiddle that shows that this works.  Why would this get a downvote without an explanation?